# How to change action bar icon when app is minimized Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I searched for similar issue but cannot find a topic that is related to this problem. I want to show a different icon when app is minimized.

Tried to add `android:logo` attribute to the application, but it did not change the icon

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/action_logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I am using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'` so the icon doesn't show in the action bar, but when minimized the icon launcher is used.

Is there a way to show a different icon in the action bar when app is minimized like below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first change android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" to what you want then click button rebuild (green button in up of Android Studion ) and create app .

Comment: `ic_launcher` is the app icon, I have no intention to change the app icon, I want to change the icon in the action bar from displaying `ic_launcher` to display `action_logo`